# Inkscape does not see fonts... But I need them

Tags: inkscape, fonts, improvement

Yes, like the ***title explains***, Inkscape ignore some fonts.
Here's an example:

[image: OMG Where's Helvetica?]

I need those fonts because they come from a very large project and I don't know how to replace them.

Replacing those fonts would be a problem due to space issues and the integrity of the documents where the modified images will be inserted.

[image: You can't do this to me!]

Ok if the fonts are not implemented but, can't I **import them into Inkscape?**
Thanks for attenctions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't "import" fonts into Inkscape.  Inskcape use the system fonts installed on your computer. If you don't have the fonts installed, Inkscape can't use them or display them.

You can buy these fonts [from Linotype](https://www.linotype.com/1264118/neue-helvetica-55-roman-product.html?SiteId=574), they're not free unfortunately.